# How to use pass-by-reference arguments of template type in method templates?

Tags: c++, templates, methods, pass-by-reference

I am currently struggling to get the following code to compile. First the header file containing a class with a method template:

```
// ConfigurationContext.h

class ConfigurationContext
{
    public:
    template<typename T> T getValue(const std::string& name, T& default) const
        {
            ...
        }
}
```

Somewhere else I want to call this method like this:

```
int value = context.getValue<int>("foo", 5);
```

There I get the following error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'ConfigurationContext::getValue(const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, int)'
```

I checked the obvious errors like missing includes and stuff like that. But everything seems to be right. I tried removing the pass-by-reference of the template type argument like this:

```
template<typename T> T getValue(const std::string& name, T default) const ...
```

Then it compiles without any errors and also runs fine, but I'd still like to pass in a reference here...

Does anybody know whats happening here and how to make this work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`5` is a literal, and you cannot bind literals to non-`const` references. Either take `T` per copy or per `const` reference:

```
template<typename T> T getValue(const std::string& name, const T& def) const
```

(BTW, I doubt that your compiler accepts `T default`, because `default` is a keyword and must not be used as an identifier.)

The reason you cannot do this is because taking arguments per non-`const` reference usually implies that the callee might change the value and such changes should reflect at the caller's. (See [How to pass objects to functions in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139224/how-to-pass-objects-to-functions-in-c/2139254#2139254)) However, you cannot change literals or temporaries. So you are not allowed to pass them to non-`const` references.

Comment: Of course, that makes sense now... I should probably not code anymore at this time (2:46 CEST). Thanks for this quick help! (Oh and I don't actually use T default in my code, just shortened everything to make it more clear...)

Comment: I am wondering why the compiler can't give a meaningful message in this case.

Comment: @chubsdad: C++ is a such wicked language to parse, implementers are pretty busy trying to make their compilers accept _valid_ code and making the right guesses about what went wrong in case of invalid code takes time. (Comeau, probably the most standard-conforming compiler, also comes with very good error messages.) And, for C++ standards, this error message isn't all that bad. At least it's not really _misleading_. (Remove the semicolon at the end of the declaration of a class which is the last thing in some header if you want to see an error message that's misleading for newbies.)