# Type condition in C++ template class problem

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

Using GCC 4.2.
I have this metatemplate for conditional type:

```
template <bool condition, typename Then, typename Else>
struct IF
{
    typedef Then RET;
};

template <class Then, class Else>
struct IF<false, Then, Else>
{
    typedef Else RET;
};
```

and when I use it like this:

```
template <typename T>
class Param
{
    IF< sizeof(int)<sizeof(long), long, int>::RET  i;
};
```

it works, but when I use it like this (trying to use template parameters):

```
template <typename T>
class Param
{
    IF< sizeof(int)<sizeof(long), T&, T* >::RET mParam;
};
```

I am getting this error code:

```
error: type 'IF<false, T&, T*>' is not derived from type 'Param<T>'
```

Why is it happening? How to solve it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/if-c.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the second case, what `RET` is, depends on the template type `T`. The compiler needs to be assured that it is going to be a type in all possible instantiations (and not perhaps a static member of some instantiation of IF). You do so with the `typename` keyword.

```
template <typename T>
class Param
{
    typename IF< sizeof(int)<sizeof(long), T&, T* >::RET mParam;

};
```

Comment: Hm, couldn't we use Clang to auto-answer those `typename` questions? :)